# Checkstyle: How to Resolve "Hidden Field" Error

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

I am getting this checkstyle error:

```
'serverURL' hides a field
```

in this

```
 private static void setServerURL(final String serverURL) {
    Utility.serverURL = serverURL;
 }
```

What could be the reason, and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 64):

There is already a variable defined `serverURL` which is available to this method (additional to the formal parameter you are accepting).  This is called "shadowing".

I think most Java programmers turn this check off, because it's not really that confusing.

For example, this would trigger the error:

```
public class Foo {
  private int bar = 0;

  public void someMethod(int bar) {
    // There are two bars!  All references in this method will use the parameter bar,
    // unless they are explicitly prefixed with 'this'.
    this.bar = bar;
  }
}
```

Comment: As you see method is static, i can not use this

Comment: @CoryKendall  What do you propose is the solution to this problem?

Comment: The solution is to turn off the check, or chance the name of one of the `bar`s to something else.

Comment: This answer could be improved by specifying how to turn off that checkstyle.

Answer (score 53):

I think it is very common in constructors and setters that the set field name is the same as the setter parameter name. This is why i recommend this configuration:

```
<module name="HiddenField" >
    <property name="ignoreSetter" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreConstructorParameter" value="true" />
</module>
```

This way the other hidden field cases are still forbidden.

Comment: still not working with above properties in my checkstyle xml file.

Answer (score 10):

The parameter and the static field have the same name. Just rename one of them.
Some people follow a naming convention that prefixes all parameters with `p`. Then you would have `serverURL` as field name and `pServerURL` as parameter name.
Or you could simply turn off the check.

Answer (score 7):

I resolved it by disabling it in eclipse. I was looking for how to do that when I landed on this page. I didn't find the answer in top 10 google query so I had to figure it out the hard way. For someone who is looking for that, here is how I did it:

Open

Eclipse>Preferences>Checkstyle

Find the checkstyle configuration you are using (you might have set that or your are using default in which case its a better idea to create a copy of your own and then edit that). Select that and then click the configure button on the right side. Find the following config in the list:

Coding Problems>Hidden Field

Open the configuration (there is button called 'open' in the UI).

Unselect 'Parameter Declaration'. Click OK then Click OK and then Click OK.

Comment: For some reason my check style had multiple "hidden field" options under "Coding Problems". I disabled all of them then only enabled one and followed the directions above and it worked. Wanted to do a plug for clarification in case others have the same problem.

Comment: How about fixing the code than to turn of the checker? see Cory Kendall's answer

Comment: @Hannes Sure. That is exactly the solution **checkstyle** is suggesting to the user. However people landing on this page are looking for ways to make checkstyle stop warning for that.

Answer (score 5):

Just change ur param name in ur method

```
private static void setServerURL(final String serverURL) {
Utility.serverURL = serverURL;
}
```

to

```
private static void setServerURL(final String serverURLXYZ) {
Utility.serverURL = serverURLXYZ;
}
```

Enjoy...

Jigar Patel

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhhh!

Comment: This isn't a clean solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I read the documnetation :

https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/coding/HiddenFieldCheck.html

Here is the solution:

```
<module name="HiddenField">
   <property name="tokens" value="VARIABLE_DEF"/>
 </module>
```

If already have a HiddentField tag, then add the tokens property.

I had a similar issue, with this fix everything works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Kinda dumb error, but here is the easy fix I put in my setters to fix it:

was:

```
public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
}
```

updated:

```
public void setName(String val) {
  this.name = val;
}
```

Comment: This isn't a clean solution :)

Comment: @th3an0maly With the checkstyle restrictions, this is the simplest thing I could figure out. What is something cleaner that you suggest?